# Testing that all actions in a controller allow only authenticated users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing

I have a small REST API in my Rails 4 app. Basically it is a controller with 7 actions. Only authenticated users are allowed to access the API and checks were added as before_filter from Devise gem. What is the best way to test this?

I already have unit tests for the API where I manually test each action if it requires authentication, but I don't like this obviously.

Comment: With minitest, test-unit or rspec?

Comment: @max I use rspec, but I am looking for general ideas how to remove boilerplate code. I would appreciate any examples though

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In RSpec you can [use shared examples](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/shared-examples):

```
# spec/support/shared_examples/authentication.rb
RSpec.shared_examples "an authenticated action" do |action|
  it "requires authentication" do
    expect { action.call }.to raise_exception("uncaught throw :warden")
  end
end
```

---

```
require 'rails_helper'
require 'support/shared_examples/authentication'

RSpec.describe PetsController do
  describe "GET #index" do
   it_behaves_like "an authenticated action", { get :index }
  end
  describe "PATCH #update" do
   it_behaves_like "an authenticated action", { patch :update, { pet: { name: 'Moon Moon' }} }
  end
  describe "DELETE #destroy" do
   it_behaves_like "an authenticated action", { delete :destroy, id: 1 }
  end
end
```